# Cannot access collection by properties Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have three different arrays with the same length in the request and below is how I combine them into one collection:

```
$inputs = collect();
$keys = collect(['id', 'username', 'email']);
foreach ($request['ids'] as $index => $id) {
   $username = $request['usernames'][$index];
   $email = $request['emails'][$index];
   $inputs->push($keys->combine([$id, $username, $email]));
}
```

The result looks correct to me:

[image]

However, I cannot access the collection when I iterate over it:

```
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    dd($input->id); // Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
}
```

This is the result of dd($input):

[image]

Any pointers on this problem? (Another short way to combine the arrays into one collection will also be appreciated!)

Thank you.

Comment: `dd($input)` instead `dd($input->id)` and see the result you will see your problem

Comment: updated! Still, don't know how to solve the problem, any help from you will be appreciated!

Comment: you are trying to access collection items as object properties, it wont work. try `$input['id']` or  `$input->get('id')`

Comment: Ohhh, so that's how laravel collection work, I thought it would work just as eloquent. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a collection and you should get it like this: `dd($input['id'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine arrays bt array_merge

```
array_merge($a1,$a2)
```

or collect

```
$c=collect([$arr1,$arr2])
```

then pluck if you want

```
$c->pluck('username')
```